# Not able to open my app-debug.apk after uploading it to drive

Tags: android, spring-boot, google-drive-api

i rebuilt my android studio project and then generated the apk. I then uploaded the apk on my google drive. When i tried to download the apk on phone i got this error :

Unable to access document. Reason : Connection Error. Please make sure you have an active connection to the internet and try again.

I gave the app user-permissions Internet and everything . It was  a simple CRUD app connected to spring boot backend server. but now i cannot open the apk file from drive.

What can i do to fix this ?

Comment: download from web https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive